# Change image based on wrapper height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a script that looks at the height of all the postInside wrappers on a page. If the height of each individual wrapper is less than 320px, I want to add a style to an image within that particular wrapper.

Here is my code.  Any feedback would be great.

```
jQuery('div.postInside').each(function(){
  var div = jQuery('div.postInside').height();
  var wrapper = jQuery('div.postInside');
  if (div < 320){
    jQuery('p.imageCenter img').attr('style','max-width:250px !important');
    delete wrapper;
    delete div
   }
});
```

Comment: One quick mistake- You only delete those variables if div<320.. You should be deleting them outside of the if statement to make sure they get deleted. That's a leak.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
jQuery('div.postInside').each(function(){
  if (jQuery(this).height() < 320) {
    jQuery(this).children('img').css('max-width','250px !important');
   }
});
```